# Running DWSIM failed

Tags: 12.10, xubuntu, mono

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 with mono-complete installed. Being a chemical engineer I required some 'Process Simulation' application & I found it in DWSIM. I used [this](http://dwsim.inforside.com.br/wiki/index.php?title=Running_DWSIM_on_Ubuntu).

However it failed to ran with the following output:

```
mono /home/usa/Downloads/DWSIM_Mono_Edit...h_b4503_to_4606/DWSIM.exe
Missing method System.Type::op_Equality(Type,Type) in assembly /usr/lib/mono/2.0/mscorlib.dll, referenced in assembly /usr/lib/mono/gac/UIAutomationProvider/3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/UIAutomationProvider.dll
Error setting up UIA: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Windows.Automation.Provider.AutomationInteropProvider ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Type.op_Equality'.
  at System.Windows.Automation.Provider.BridgeManager.GetAutomationBridges () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Automation.Provider.AutomationInteropProvider..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.UIAutomation.Winforms.FormListener.Initialize () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.UIAutomation.Winforms.Global.Initialize () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Application.InitializeUIAutomation () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'DWSIM.FormMain' from assembly 'DWSIM, Version=2.1.4606.29773, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
  at DWSIM.My.MyProject+MyForms.get_FormMain () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at DWSIM.My.MyApplication.OnCreateMainForm () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run (System.String[] commandLine) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at DWSIM.My.MyApplication.Main (System.String[] Args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'DWSIM.FormMain' from assembly 'DWSIM, Version=2.1.4606.29773, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
  at DWSIM.My.MyProject+MyForms.get_FormMain () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at DWSIM.My.MyApplication.OnCreateMainForm () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run (System.String[] commandLine) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at DWSIM.My.MyApplication.Main (System.String[] Args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: You mentioned `Ubuntu` in your question but tagged the question with `Xubuntu` which one actually you're using?

Comment: am using xubuntu... I thought the only difference is the desktop they are using but lets not transgress into those details

Comment: Where did you download `dwsim` from? I cannot open the link mentioned in [this page](http://dwsim.inforside.com.br/wiki/index.php?title=Running_DWSIM_on_Ubuntu).

Comment: I downloaded via official link http://sourceforge.net/projects/dwsim/

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the following packages + dependancies (worked for me on ubuntu 12.04):

```
libmono-microsoft-visualbasic10.0-cil 
libmono-system-Data-Linq4.0-cil
libmono-system-xml-Linq4.0-cil
```