# Installing Miramath in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, dependencies

I tried building this application via downloading from http://sourceforge.net/projects/miramath/?source=dlp & in the process have already downloaded +500mb data but at one point I am constantly failing...
This was the output that I finally got after install many dependencies:

```
sudo python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 28, in <module>
    from mainwindow import *
  File "/home/usama/Downloads/miramath/mainwindow.py", line 24, in <module>
    import worksheet
  File "/home/usama/Downloads/miramath/worksheet.py", line 37, in <module>
    import polarplot
  File "/home/usama/Downloads/miramath/polarplot.py", line 30, in <module>
    from polarplotwidget import PolarPlotWidget
  File "/home/usama/Downloads/miramath/polarplotwidget.py", line 29, in <module>
    class PolarPlotWidget(Qwt.QwtPolarPlot):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'QwtPolarPlot'
```

so I downloaded PyQwt via http://sourceforge.net/projects/miramath/files/PyQwt-Polar/

as per the manual I navigated to the configure folder & ran:

```
python configure.py -Q ../qwt-5.2
Command line options:
{'debug': False,
 'disable_numarray': False,
 'disable_numeric': False,
 'disable_numpy': False,
 'excluded_features': [],
 'extra_cflags': [],
 'extra_cxxflags': [],
 'extra_defines': [],
 'extra_include_dirs': [],
 'extra_lflags': [],
 'extra_lib_dirs': [],
 'extra_libs': [],
 'jobs': '',
 'module_install_path': '',
 'modules': [],
 'qt': 4,
 'qwt_sources': '../qwt-5.2',
 'sip_include_dirs': [],
 'subdirs': [],
 'timelines': [],
 'trace': ''}

Found SIP-4.13.3.
Found 'posix' operating system:
2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2012, 21:53:58) 
[GCC 4.7.2]
Do not get upset by error messages in the next 3 compiler checks:
Check if 'size_t' and 'unsigned int' are the same type:
YES
Check if 'size_t' and 'unsigned long' are the same type:
size_t_check.cpp:3:6: error: prototype for ‘void a::f(long unsigned int)’ does not match any in class ‘a’
size_t_check.cpp:2:24: error: candidate is: void a::f(size_t)
NO
Check if 'size_t' and 'unsigned long long' are the same type:
size_t_check.cpp:3:6: error: prototype for ‘void a::f(long long unsigned int)’ does not match any in class ‘a’
size_t_check.cpp:2:24: error: candidate is: void a::f(size_t)
NO
Failed to import numarray: PyQwt will be build without support for numarray.

Failed to find Numeric2: PyQwt will be build without support for Numeric.

Found NumPy-1.6.2.

g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_WEBKIT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4 -I../qwt-5.2/src -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I. -o qwt_version_info.o qwt_version_info.cpp
g++ -Wl,-O1 -o qwt_version_info qwt_version_info.o    -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -lQtCore -lpthread 
Found Qwt-5.2.1.

Extended command line options:
{'debug': False,
 'disable_numarray': False,
 'disable_numeric': False,
 'disable_numpy': False,
 'excluded_features': ['-x HAS_PYQT_031105',
                       '-x HAS_NUMARRAY',
                       '-x HAS_NUMERIC',
                       '-x HAS_QWT4'],
 'extra_cflags': [],
 'extra_cxxflags': [],
 'extra_defines': ['HAS_NUMPY'],
 'extra_include_dirs': ['/usr/include/python2.7',
                        '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include'],
 'extra_lflags': [],
 'extra_lib_dirs': [],
 'extra_libs': [],
 'iqt': 'iqt5qt4',
 'iqt_sipfile': '../sip/iqt5qt4/IQtModule.sip',
 'jobs': '',
 'module_install_path': '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt4/Qwt5',
 'modules': ['iqt', 'Qwt5'],
 'qt': 4,
 'qwt': 'qwt5qt4',
 'qwt_sipfile': '../sip/qwt5qt4/QwtModule.sip',
 'qwt_sources': '../qwt-5.2',
 'sip_include_dirs': [],
 'subdirs': ['iqt5qt4', 'qwt5qt4'],
 'timelines': ['-t Qwt_5_2_0'],
 'trace': ''}

The following modules will be built: ['iqt', 'Qwt5'].

Setup the PyQwt package build.
sip invokation:
'/usr/bin/sip -b tmp-iqt5qt4/iqt5qt4.sbf -c tmp-iqt5qt4   ../sip/iqt5qt4/IQtModule.sip'
sh: 1: /usr/bin/sip: not found
SIP failed to generate the C++ code.
```

How can I resolve this?

---

The above problems were resolved via installing: python-qt4-dev  libqwt-dev python-sip-dev python-dev

After successfully building PyQwt I faced a new error while running miramath

```
 python main.py
running...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 77, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "main.py", line 51, in main
    main = MainWindow()
  File "/home/usama/Downloads/miramath/mainwindow.py", line 55, in __init__
    self.addTab()
  File "/home/usama/Downloads/miramath/mainwindow.py", line 436, in addTab
    w = worksheet.WorkSheet(self, self.runtimeStatusMessage, self.numEquationsStatusMessage, self.currentEquationStatusMessage)
  File "/home/usama/Downloads/miramath/worksheet.py", line 94, in __init__
    self.execution_thread = execthread.ExecThread(self)
  File "/home/usama/Downloads/miramath/execthread.py", line 56, in __init__
    exec symbolics_init_program in self.symbolics_global_namespace    # execfile goes away in 3.0
  File "<string>", line 91, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'abs'
```

Problem is resolved @green7 answer's below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open the file `symbolics_init.py`.
- Go to line `91`.
- Replace `sympy.abs` with `sympy.Abs`

Comment: `python-qwt5-qt4 python-qwt3d-qt4 python3-ply python-ply python-sympy python-scipy python-qt4' thesee all are already installed?

Comment: Are the errors, that you mentioned, from PyQwt package or miramath?

Comment: ok done, the errors are resolved & now I have successfully installed  PyQwt package...However while running miramath splash screen occurs & terminal shows the following error...I repeat no further error from PyQwt occurs: http://pastebin.com/bWTqRQRU

Comment: I've modified the answer. Since the problem you're facing now is different from that in the question, I request you to please modify the question as well. :)

Comment: Extremely thnx, as an engineer I like to run educational apps in this aspect please also make your input to: http://askubuntu.com/questions/279920/running-dwsim-failed

Comment: Glad it worked. I'll look into that question. :)